# (Order of) multiplicity of primefactor 2 in the integers near $N$'th root of $2^S$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Consider the $N$'th root of $2^S$ . This roots are noninteger (irrational) when $S/N$ is noninteger. To avoid duplicates consider in the following only $S$ for a given $N$ when $\gcd(N,S)=1$.
Let's assume $N, S\in \mathbb N^+$, $S>N$ (and $\gcd(S,N)=1$ when we want avoid duplicates). Let's denote $R=S/N$ and assume $S,N$ such that this rational value $R>1$. Let's then denote $\rho = 2^R$ .

Now I am interested in the multiplicity of the primefactor $2$ in the neighboured integers, say $m_l = \lfloor \rho \rfloor $ and $m_u = \lceil \rho \rceil = m_l+1 $. Because only one can have the primefactor $2$ we can introduce
$$ A_{N,S} = \nu_2 (m_l \cdot m_u) $$
where  $\nu_2(\cdot)$ means the *valuation* for the primefactor $2$.

Using small $N$ and looking at $S$ up to $1000$, heuristics seem to indicate that $A$ is roughly of logarithmic order depending on $S$.

> Can we have an upper bound for $A$ depending on $S$ (if we keep $N$ constant)?

The heuristics remind me a bit of the primefactors $p^k$ in the canonical primefacorization of the cyclotomic expressions $a^n-1 $ depending on increasing $n$ - however it seems much more random.

***update*** I've found an article of Bailey, Borwein, Crandall, Pomerance "On the binary representation of algebraic numbers" (2003?) which deals with this and more general problems. I found them mention that *"for large N cannot have a zero-run of more than $2\ln N$ consecutive zeros"* which is very near to what I am considering here. (chap 11, about "open problems", pg 29 of my pdf-preprint)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not yet complete, but it gives already a very instructive "formula" for determination of $A$ .
The main ingredient for the formula is the binary representation of $2^{1/N}$

- Let us assume $N=2$. The binary representation of $\rho=2^{1/2}$ is `"1.01101010000010011110011001100111..."_2`
  The valuations $\nu_2(\lfloor 2^{k-1} \rho \rfloor)$ represented as string is `s_l="10010101234501200001200120012000..."` . Accordingly we can determine `s_u="01201010000010012340012001200123..."` for the valuations of the ceilings. Having such a compact representation we can get
  `__"10010101234501200001200120012000..."` s_l (valuations in floors) counting consecutive zeros
  `"1.01101010000010011110011001100111..."_2`  bitstring for $2^{1/2}$
  `__"01201010000010012340012001200123..."` s_u (valuations in ceils) counting consecutive ones
  We can immediately see, how the exponents at primefactor $2$ in $w_l(k) = \lfloor 2^{k-1} \cdot 2^{1/2} \rfloor$ occur if we follow the zeros in the bitstring and look in the according "digit" in $s_l$ above it.
  Completely analoguous is it with the ceilings.

Of course this is not yet a full answer, how large $A(S,N)$ can become depending on $S$ and $N$. However it indicates easily how it depends on the approximation of $2^k \cdot 2^{1/N}$ to the unit, and this obviously encoded in the bitstring-representation of $\rho_N=2^{1/N}$ Thus the Baker's approximation-rules occur here. As we deal with $N'th$ roots of $2$ here, we'll find not very well diophantine approximations as that fractions are irrational, but still algebraic, numbers. I think I've seen research on the numbers of consecutive zeros (or ones) in the bitstring of irrational numbers (however maybe of $\log_2(3)$ instead, have it not at hand) but I think it is reasonable guess, that by this $A(S,N)$ grows at most logarithmically with perhaps finitely many exceptions.

One more example:

- Let us assume $N=3$. The binary representation of $\rho=2^{1/3}$ is `"1.01000010100010100010111110011000..."_2`
  The valuations $\nu_2(\lfloor 2^{k-1} \rho \rfloor)$ represented as string is `s_l="10123401012301012301000001200123..."` . Accordingly we can determine `s_u="01000010100010100010123450012000..."` for the valuations of the ceilings. Having such a compact representation we can write
  `__"10123401012301012301000001200123..."` s_l (valuations in floors) counting consecutive zeros
  `"1.01000010100010100010111110011000..."_2`  bitstring for $2^{1/3}$
  `__"01000010100010100010123450012000..."` s_u (valuations in ceilings) counting consecutive ones